# How to stream records from a web service in a spring batch like JDBCCursorItemReader

Tags: stream, spring-batch, batch-processing, chunking

Use case is to read a large set of data from a REST web service, List of million objects, process them and write them back somewhere. Issue is that I do not want to read ALL the data from the web service in one go. I would like to read a subset of the total results from the web service,a few records/objects at a time, so that I do not run the risk of running out of memory by reading all the data in one go from the spring batch reader. Is there a way to do this? Spring Batch provides `ItemReaderAdapter` for reading from external service (as opposed to from database or flat file) but it does nothing special except giving support for delegating some calls. I would like to do something that `JDBCCursorItemReader` where it reads, or rather streams from the db instead of reading all at once.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/73040-default-webservice-reader-implementation Here they talk about the lack of a reader for web services.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25025898/153940 also mentions how Spring Batch doesn't have a web service `ItemReader`

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that Spring Batch does not provide a web service `ItemReader` implementation.  The reason for that is that the definition of "web service" is a bit too vague to be able to standardize a reader around.

That being said, you could implement your own quite easily by extending the `AbstractPagingItemReader` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractPagingItemReader.html) and adding the logic appropriate for your web service there.